# how can i define an interface that contains a function and specific its return type base on another paramter?

Tags: typescript

i defined an interface like this

```
interface IConfigParams
{
dataKey:string,
loadData:()=>Promise<any>
}
```

now i want replace the `any` type in promise into a specfic object define based on the `dataKey` value.

which is something like `{[dataKey]:any}`

for example, if `dataKey` current value is `list`,then the return type of `loadData`,should be `Promise<{list:any}>`

how can i make it?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to introduce the value of your `dataKey` property into the type system, for example by using a generic type with a `DataKey` string literal type:

```
type DataKey<S> = S extends string ? string extends S ? never : S : never;

interface IConfigParams<S extends string> {
  dataKey: DataKey<S>;
  loadData:() => Promise<{[key in DataKey<S>]: any}>;
}

const listConfigParams: IConfigParams<'list'> = {
  dataKey: 'list',
  loadData: async () => ({ list: 'some value' })
};
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5&ssl=9&ssc=19&pln=10&pc=49#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBpCIA8BlAfFAvFDKCAD2AgDsATAZymuACcBLcgcygH47GX2SyqtQl3IQAbhAZQAXARlRREhgG4AsACgNLMgwBmcAMbQAkgGEA9uV1NWABTgM4AW2qYipCjW7M2OAN4aUFCUCMiosvCIKOjYaupBADbmcJSRcNIAFACUeDi2DOZOTNQQaH4A2gDWqFAssKHRmFgAurJw5CAAvlhxnRoaBpb0UAnFwBZWNvaOLrJmltZ2Ds6uAOSj9Ks4+AHxwQ3hUOtjqwA0gSPJqaFt1CDkBlDZuU9+I2Oyq9SF0GJwCQBXCCrKCdLIaTpxIA)</sup>

---

You could avoid having to specify the string literal twice by creating a factory function that automatically infers the type:

```
function createConfigParams<S extends string>(
  dataKey: DataKey<S>,
  loadData: () => Promise<{[key in DataKey<S>]: any}>
): IConfigParams<S> {
  return { dataKey, loadData };
}

const listConfigParams = createConfigParams('list', async () => ({ list: '' }));
```

Comment: can we make it more smarter and automaticly, i mean not define `list` twice.  by the way, in your solution, what's different if i do not use 'DataKey<S>', but just use 'S' directly. 
```
interface IConfigParams<S extends string> {
  dataKey:<S>;
  loadData:() => Promise<{[key in S]: any}>;
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it can be made smarter. As far as I know, there's no way for an interface to refer to itself, but I might be wrong. The change you suggested would allow you to define objects with a type `IConfigParams<string>` without requiring an actual string literal.